# Why did Hisoka want to kill Phantom Troupe's members?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I am not quite understanding why Hisoka tried to kill all Phantom Troupe member after he lost to its leader, Chrollo Lucifer. That fight, Chrollo vs Hisoka, I think is reasonable because Hisoka always intended to beat a person that more powerful than himself,

> but in the end he lost and was also confirmed dead by Shalnark.

From the very first Phantom Troupe's Arc, Hisoka doesn't seem to have that kind of urge to kill all Phantom troupe's member. After his rebirth from that battle between Chrollo Lucifer, he suddenly does have the urge to kill all of Phantom Troupes' member, this just escalated quickly mood from Hisoka. His first Victim from the group were

> Shalnark and Kortopi, in chapter 357

What's his motive to kill all Phantom Troupe's member?

Answer (score 3):

The thing is, it's quite hard to interpret or understand Hisoka's motives. So, as to the reason behind Hisoka's seemingly abrupt decision to kill or hunt down all Phantom Troupe members, **we don't know yet as of now unless it will be revealed in upcoming chapters**. **Chapter 357** also surprised me as his decision was so sudden.

What we do know, either from reading the manga or watching the anime, is that Hisoka is someone who gets off or is 'turned on' [when fighting someone who is strong](https://hunterxhunter.fandom.com/wiki/Hisoka_Morow), either stronger than him like Chrollo or someone with potential like Gon. This could probably mean that he either has [Agonophilia](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Agonophilia) or he's an [adrenaline junkie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrenaline#Adrenaline_junkie). He probably wants to fight all of the Troupe members, believing it would give him great arousal or excitement since *he probably realized they could be worthy opponents after his fight with Chrollo*. But again, this is just a possibility based on his actions. We can't be sure unless Togashi explicitly shows this in the future.

It would be, however, hasty to immediately conclude that he did it 'just because' with no reason or plan. He's not like that and he plans all his moves, as can be seen, for example, in his fights during the [Heavens Arena arc](https://hunterxhunter.fandom.com/wiki/Heavens_Arena_arc). *As to his exact plans for antagonizing all of the members of the Troupe, it also has yet to be revealed*.

Comment: but, in chapter 357, he defeated some of phantom troupe member easily because their ability were "stolen" by chrollo. It's contradicted, since what i know Hisoka only want to fight person when they are in good condition to fight against him.

Comment: @Gagantous 'Hisoka only want to fight person when they are in good condition to fight against him' During the Hunter Exam, this was not the case, though. Remember how he killed those group of people in that misty area? Or when he killed someone just out of pure bloodlust when Gon was tailing him? The Troupe has no quarrel with him but by killing 2 of their members, he's made enemies with all of them. This was probably in the hopes of fighting all or some of them at the same time. But again, this is just speculation based on how much he craves excitement from fighting.

Answer (score 1):

From the first instance where we learned that Hisoka was trying to fight the leader of the Phantom Troupe Chrollo Lucifer, one of the major obstacles in his path were the other members of the Phantom troupe, several of whom were formidable nen users, and some are at least comparable to Hisoka's combat abilities. If Hisoka turned against the leader the other members would not allow him the fight, and would run interference.

Most of Hisoka's actions during the Phantom Troupe vs Kurapika arc is motivated by him wanting to physically separate Chrollo Lucifer from the rest of the members, and have a 1 v 1 matchup. Which didn't come to pass, seeing as how

> Kurapika sealed Chrollo's nen abilities.

When he did finally manage to weasel out a neutral match out of him, Chrollo insisted that it take place in Heaven's arena, after he had enough prep time. During their match, Chrollo used several of his new abilities, stored in the dictionary. Furthermore, he borrowed abilities of fellow troupe members Machi, Shalnark and Kortopi, and involved the crowd gathered in the arena as disposable pawns, to essentially kill Hisoka. It is implied that these three had further involvement in his loss, seeing how the exact three members were present after the match, to confirm Hisoka's death.

But, after

> resurrecting himself using his post mortem nen

Hisoka restrains Machi and declares that he is going to hunt every Troupe member that he will come across.

Shortly after he

> confronts Shalnark and Kortopi and kills them with ease; decapitating Kortopi, and leaving Shalnark's corpse as a macarbe display for Chrollo.

While it is not stated outright, it is implied that Hisoka came to the conclusion, that as long as the limbs of the spider are present, he would never get to have a true 1 v 1 with chrollo.

---

It is also possible that Hisoka saw Chrollo borrowing the troupes abilities during their match, as them 'intruding' on their duel. Despite being a murderous psychopath with a fetish for fighting strong opponents, Hisoka has his own set of (twisted) code of conduct. Somewhat similar to a perverted version of the 'warrior's way'. Which is part of the reason why he admires fighters like Gon, who value the agreement between fighters and comes at him with no underhanded tactics, and nothing held back.

As soon as he was revived, his mind was already planning their next duel. Realizing that the other Phantom members are always going to be an obstacle, he decides to eliminate them all, before going after the head of the spider. Plus, by going after and killing the exact 2 out of 3 members from whom Chrollo borrowed abilities, and thus 'intruded' on their duel, he is sending a message to Chrollo. That being, 'you had them interfere in their match, and now your actions have led to their deaths'. This will work, as we have already seen how, despite being sociopathic mass murderers with no morals, the Troupe members care for their own, and would go ballistic when a member is harmed.

Happened when

> Uvogin was killed, and same thing happened now. Seeing as how now, the entire troupe is abroad the Kakin expedition ship to the Dark continent. I would go as far as to say that, Hisoka's managed to confine the notoriously slippery phantoms in one location, with little chance of wiggling their way out, or escape.

Much like Rorsharch says in Watchmen, "I'm not locked in here with you, you're locked in here with me"

Personal Note: I would be ecstatic if the successor arc concluded with Hisoka having curb stomped, most if not all spiders, especially Chrollo. Go for team Hisoka. (I know that rooting for a psychopath killer over some sociopath career criminals might not seem that good of a position to take, but what can I say.)

Answer (score 0):

It's because hisoka fought chrollo and chrollo used the phantom troupes powers to aid him in the fight, so he's going to kill them all in order to have a fair fight with chrollo.
because killing the user removes the ability from chrollo's book.

Comment: So why he didnt kill mari ? She is phantom troupe member after all

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references. Because stealing abilities also results to the original user unable to use that ability anymore.

Comment: @Gagantous Because she healed him after getting defeated from chrollo.

Comment: @W.Are Chrollo took Shalnark and Korotopi's Hatsu to defeat Hisoka, Hunter × Hunter - Volume 34, Chapter 351
Chrollo asks if they wants their abilites back, Hunter × Hunter - Volume 34, Chapter 357
They allow Chrollo to keep them and die to hisoka defenseless.

Comment: @W.Are Killing the owner of an ability Erases the ability from Chrollos book  Hunter × Hunter - Volume 34, Chapter 352

Comment: @Nick I don't think that's enough reason for Hisoka to spare Machi. Also, while killing the owner erases the ability, that does not really explain why Hisoka wanted to kill them all. Chrollo didn't steal all their abilities and even with them dead, Chrollo can still acquire more. I doubt the Spiders' abilities are only the abilities he stole or is keeping in his book. So I don't think that because he wanted to have a fair fight is a reason.

Comment: @Nick Also, Machi sees him as enemy now. I doubt that he can still force her to heal him. He might as well have killed her there as she's also a formidable enemy. But he didn't, and the reason is not clear yet...

Comment: @W.Are It's very troublesome for chrollo to steal an ability, His phantom Troupe are 100% willing to allow him to take their abilities (especially because he can return them). The Phantom troupe members have good abilities and they make it easier for chrollo to steal. Hisoka wanted to see Chrollo's Strength not a combined effort from the other Phantom troupe. That's not what makes Hisoka erect.

Comment: @W.Are Also, Hisoka wanted to take Machi on a date during Heavens arena after she healed him from the battle with kastro. He just likes her, Thats the only reasoning the fans can go off of from reading where I left off. All the info I have is before the Kakin Boat Arc. Either Togashi hasn't wrote another reasoning for Machi to stay alive, Hisoka liking her is enough or I just need to keep reading.

Comment: @Nick 'Also, Hisoka wanted to take Machi on a date during Heavens arena after she healed him from the battle with kastro.' If that's how you interpret it, okay. But Hisoka was just flirting. Can we really truly say he wanted to take Machi on a date because he was serious about her?

Comment: @Nick Chrollo seems formidable enough even without the Phantom Troupe's abilities (IIIRC, he did not have any of the abilities from the Phantom Troupe when he fought the Zoldycks). So I don't think he relies that much on the Spiders' abilities. He's strong, even without the troupe's help.

Comment: @W.Are I have no idea man, but i answered the question. The literal reason for her being alive is because he likes her. Whether he's just flirting or not is subjective and irrelevant to the original question.

Comment: @W.Are More reasoning that hisoka just likes her.
https://i.imgur.com/alYNF10.jpg

Comment: @W.Are also its not about chrollo being strong, its chrollo denying hisoka from seeing what he actually fights like.

Answer (score 0):

probably hisoka realized that lying in wait made him become rusty. Evidence is that when he fought chrollo, the latter showed off his offensive strategies, while the former observed in amazement. After his rebirth, hisoka considers he might have caused his own loss and swears to become a new person entirely.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion its because, whenever Hisoka was fighting with Chrollo, he was actually 1(Hisoka) vs 4(Chrollo, Machi, Shalnark, Kortopi). And it is obviously unfair matchup. I found this video very helpful explaining hisoka reason to kill every troupe.

Part1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Km6l5gRXuY

Part2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2vsYFYMD1g

Comment: this doesn't answer the question to Hisoka's motives. if the answer is in any of the youtube link you have linked to it's best that you summarize the relevant information from then in the event the videos were to be removed

Comment: why did machi involved on that match ? chrollo didnt steal machi's ability

Comment: @Gagantous this pictures might help explain your question. 
http://i.imgur.com/dhu7ZZ6.png 

Right picture source: Chapter 355

Comment: i think that's shalnark ability, not machi

Comment: shalnark have two anthena

Comment: @Gagantous, yup perhaps he have 2 antenna, but Hisoka is holding a different kind of antenna. And most likely like Machi antenna. https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/hunterxhunter/images/3/33/Machi_2011.png/revision/latest?cb=20150614135352